# regex: remove zeros in the middle of string (but keep the ones at the end) pyspark

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to remove zeros that are in the middle of a string, while keeping the ones at the end (in pyspark). So far I have only found regex that remove leading or trailing zeros. 
Example:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
[
    ("GH0786",),
    ("HH7040",),
    ("IP0090",),
    ("AH567",),
],
["number"]
)
```

INPUT:

```
+-------+
|number |
+-------+
|GH0786 |
|HH7040 |
|IP0090 |
|AH567  |
+-------+
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
+-------+
|number |
+-------+
|GH786  |
|HH740  |
|IP90  |
|AH567  |
+-------+
```

I have thought about splitting the string at the first zero and remove the last character (the 0) of the first substring (and if the first character of the second substring starts with a zero as well, then remove the first character), but was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Comment: [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) is a great site where you can create and test regular expressions - I believe you might end up with something like this: `r"(?<=.)(0+)(?=.)"`

Comment: "IP0090" example seems to be wrong, according to you question it should be "IP009" not "IP900"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `0+(?!$)` to match zeros that are not at the end of the strings; `?!` means negative look ahead, `$` matches the end of the string so `(?!$)` matches character not at EOS:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1.withColumn('zeroRemoved', F.regexp_replace('number', '0+(?!$)', '')).show()
+------+-----------+
|number|zeroRemoved|
+------+-----------+
|GH0786|      GH786|
|HH7040|      HH740|
|IP0090|       IP90|
| AH567|      AH567|
+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The `regex_replace` method is preferred, but you could also use a `udf` for this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.Types import StringType

def remove_inner_zeroes(my_string):
    if my_string[-1] == '0':
        return my_string.replace('0', '') + '0'
    return my_string.replace('0', '')

remove_inner_zeros_udf = udf(remove_inner_zeros, StringType())
df1.withColumn('zeroRemoved', remove_inner_zeros_udf(col('number')).show()
#+------+-----------+
#|number|zeroRemoved|
#+------+-----------+
#|GH0786|      GH786|
#|HH7040|      HH740|
#|IP0090|       IP90|
#| AH567|      AH567|
#+------+-----------+
```

---

Or you could replicate the same functionality using the following spark functions:

- `pyspark.sql.Columns.endsWith()`
- `pyspark.sql.functions.replace()`
- `pyspark.sql.functions.when()`
- `pyspark.sql.functions.concat()`:

For example:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, concat, lit, replace, when

def remove_inner_zeros_spark(string_col):
    return when(
        string_col.endsWith('0'), 
        concat(replace(string_col, '0', ''), lit('0'))
    ).otherwise(replace(string_col, '0', ''))

df1.withColumn('zeroRemoved', remove_inner_zeros_spark(col('number')).show()
#+------+-----------+
#|number|zeroRemoved|
#+------+-----------+
#|GH0786|      GH786|
#|HH7040|      HH740|
#|IP0090|       IP90|
#| AH567|      AH567|
#+------+-----------+
```